# How to switch between views in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm developing ios 6 application and need to switch between 2 views.
I've done it for ios 5 in this way:

```
-(IBAction)BtnClicked:(id)sender

{

   MainViewController* mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                              bundle:nil];

   mainView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

   [self presentModalViewController:mainView animated:NO];

}
```

But for ios 6 xcode asks that `presentModalViewController` is deprecated. 
So how to do this stuff?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the UIViewController documentation, the deprecated methods and their replacements are listed right there.

presentModalViewController:animated:
Presents a modal view managed by the given view controller to the user. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead.)

check [official page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-AppendixA-DontLinkElementID_110)

Answer (score 3):

In iOS6, the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method is deprecated. You should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. Please refer to [this official document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion) for more information.